# Find the last three characters of a string with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files with the complete path in a file and output this with "Get-Content Filename" on the Comandline of Powershell. I now only want to get the last three characters. This does not seem possible with substring. What other option is there on the command line.

Comment: The last three characters of the whole file? Or the last three characters of each line in the file?

Comment: For just any string, you can do `$string -replace '.*(.{3})','$1'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Substring()`, you just need to calculate the start index manually:

```
$s = "abcdef"
if($s.Length -gt 3){
  $s.Substring($s.Length - 3) # returns "def"
} else {
  $s
}
```

You can also use the `-replace` regex operator to remove anything preceding the last three characters:

```
$s -replace '^.*(?=.{3}$)'
```

Here we don't need the length check, `-replace` will simply not alter the string if the pattern doesn't match anything.

`-replace` also works on enumerable input, so if you want to apply the operation to every line in the file, it's as simply as:

```
(Get-Content $filename) -replace '^.*(?=.{3}$)'
```

The pattern used with replace describes:

```
^          # Match start of string
.*         # Match any number of any character
(?=.{3}$)  # Pattern MUST be followed by 3 characters and the end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, (Get-Content $filename) -replace '^.*(?=.{3}$)' works fine for me.